# Schengen Visa refused twice

Tags: indian-citizens, schengen-visas, serial-refusals

My Schengen visa has been refused twice by French embassy. The reason states is that “The information submitted regarding the justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable”.”
I had given all proper documentation and can think of no reason of refusal. I am married but doing a solo trip. Though my trip covers major cities like Paris, Berne, Switzerland, Netherlands and Nice, I am also travelling to a small French town called Tonquedec. I mentioned that too in my itinerary. Is that that the visa is refused because Visa office is not sure why I am travelling there? Actually I am meeting a friend there but did not mention that in my application to avoid the hassle of him needing to get a sponsorship. What should I do next? Should I reapply and remove this town from the itinerary. If yes after how much time?

Comment: Mentioning that you were visiting a friend in Tonquedec would create no obligations on him at all. He wouldn't have to sponsor you or anything else.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Since the visa is already rejected twice do you think I should apply again now with fresh information about meeting friend at Tonquedec ?

Comment: @Manmeet Singh Just an opinion but I doubt not mentioning the visit to your friend was the major factor in two refusals. Do you have a previous travel history? Is the cost of the trip proportionate to your income/savings? Unless you can identify something in your application that can be significantly improved it’s very possible reapplying will just result in a third refusal.

Comment: @TraellerI It is true that I don’t have a previous travel history. I had 10 times the savings in my bank account of what is the per day requirement mentioned in the French visa site.